# How to set the wal_level in AWS RDS Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, aws

How do I know which `wal_level` my AWS RDS Postgres 11.1 database has?

I checked 'parameter groups', but was unable to find the `wal_level`.

Once found, how do I change it?

Comment: I'm writing this for people who can't find the setting in the Param group:
Had you checked the actual parameter group for that instance, in the Configuration tab > DB instance parameter group?
Or just the parameter groups that you find in the Custom tab of Parameter groups, which is the default tab...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To find out the wal_level you can use PSQL and execute: `show wal_level;`
You need to set `rds.logical_replication` parameter to 1. It will automatically change wal_level to logical.

I found some details [here](https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/postgresql/#amazon-rds)

Comment: Can check both with `SELECT name,setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name IN ('wal_level','rds.logical_replication');`

Comment: The original question asks "how to change it", but nobody really answered.
To change the parameter, however obviosu this might be for some, I found it tricky:
you need to identify the actual parameter group that your instance is using, even if it's the detault one, then copy it to another group with an evocative name; then change this param with the Edit function, then save, Apply immediately, and Reboot when instance is ready to be rebooted...

Answer (score 0):

With RDS Postgresql or Aurora Postgresql, you can only work on logical replication, because we can find the paramter *rds.logical_replication* and change it to 1 to enable it. But, you can't find the parameter *wal_level* or I have also tried searching for *rds.streaming_replication* to turn on streaming replication but, you cannot find them.